# COUNT number of times prior to specified time, self-join?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, self-join

For simplicity let's assume I have two tables:

`billing` with the following fields `bill_id` (primary, unique key, int), `person_id`, `bill_date`, and
`billing_detail` containing `bill_id` and `service_type`.

First of all I would like a list of clients (`person_id`) who were billed for a given range of services in a given period, so simply

```
SELECT billing.person_id, billing.bill_date
FROM   billing
INNER JOIN billing_detail ON billing.bill_id = billing_detail.bill_id
WHERE      billing_detail.service_type IN (list of services)
  AND      billing.bill_date between some_date and another_date
```

What I would like to do now is to also show how many times a given client was billed for the same range of services PRIOR to the given date.

Say the `billing` table contains:

```
1  | 1 | 1/1/2020
2  | 1 | 1/2/2020
3  | 1 | 1/3/2020
4  | 1 | 1/4/2020
4  | 1 | 2/4/2020
```

And the `billing_detail` table contains:

```
1  |  A
2  |  B
3  |  A
4  |  B
5  |  A
```

So if I was to run a report for client 1 for the period from January to April for service type A, the expected outcome would be

```
1 | 1/1/2020 | 0 (no A type service prior to this date)
1 | 1/3/2020 | 1 (One A type service prior to this date)
1 | 2/4/2020 | 2 (Two A type services prior ot this date).
```

This probably involves some kind of self-join on both tables but my tired bird-brain can't seem to come up with the answer at the moment.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` over the `person_id` and `service_type` to get the result you want, subtracting one to start the values at 0:

```
SELECT person_id, bill_date, service_type,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id, service_type ORDER BY bill_date) - 1 AS prior_services
FROM billing b
JOIN billing_detail bd ON bd.bill_id = b.bill_id
```

This will give you data for all service types:

```
person_id   bill_date   service_type    prior_services
1           2020-01-01  A               0
1           2020-01-03  A               1
1           2020-02-04  A               2
1           2020-01-02  B               0
1           2020-01-04  B               1
```

To restrict the service type, add a

```
WHERE service_type = 'A'
```

or similar.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5e6efa41220bd3059e2072903d400698)

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Have just realised I can do it this way.  Too tired.  There is actually another question I need to ask so will re-word the question in a moment.

Comment: @MichalRosa if it is significantly different you should ask a new question...