# Count over a rolling period

Tags: sql-server-2016, rolling-computation

[This is a follow-up to my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61586269/count-number-of-times-prior-to-specified-time-self-join).  The question is similar to my original one, with an added twist that I would like to see the count of prior services for a set running period.  So say I have a table:

```
id | client |date    | service
1  |     1  | 1/2010 | A
2  |     1  | 1/2011 | A
3  |     1  | 1/2012 | A
4  |     1  | 1/2015 | A
```

I can count how many times each service was performed prior to a given date using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client, service ORDER BY date) - 1` but how do I go about a query showing the number of services performed prior to the given date but also within any given rolling period?

So say I would like to know how many A-type services were done in the last 2 years only.  The expected result would be:

```
client |date    | no of prior services
    1  |1/2010  | 0
    1  |1/2011  | 1
    1  |1/2012  | 2
    1  |1/2015  | 0 - no earlier services within the last two years.
```

What I have is something like

```
select table0.*, count(table1.date)
from table table0
left outer join table table1
  ON table0.client = table1.client
 AND table0.date > table1.date
 AND table1.date > DATEADD(year, -3, table0.date)
```

But that doesn't quite seem to be working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a query based on the tables from your previous question (which I've joined in a CTE for convenience).

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT b.bill_id, b.person_id, b.bill_date, bd.service_type
  FROM billing b
  JOIN billing_detail bd ON bd.bill_id = b.bill_id
)
SELECT c1.person_id, c1.bill_date, c1.service_type,
       COUNT(c2.bill_date) AS prior_services
FROM CTE c1
LEFT JOIN CTE c2 ON c2.person_id = c1.person_id
                AND c2.service_type = c1.service_type
                AND c2.bill_date >= DATEADD(YEAR, -2, c1.bill_date) 
                AND c2.bill_date < c1.bill_date
GROUP BY c1.person_id, c1.bill_date, c1.service_type
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ac256c72ce17cd1a044fe483264227ce)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get the dates logic right yesterday, brain not working.  I also used a CTE to join the tables in my actual query.  Your help is appreciated.